# VectorScale Explanation

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm having great difficulty understanding `VectorScale`. Here are the definitions from the documentation.

> With the explicit specification `VectorScale -> {unitlen,aratio,sfun}` each field vector is constrained to fit in a ***vector box*** oriented in the direction of the field, centered at the location of the vector.
>
> The `unitlen` is given as a fraction of the diagonal of the overall bounding box and is used as a local scale for vector boxes, `aratio` is the aspect ratio for vector boxes, `sfun` is a scaling function that determines the width of vector boxes.

I've used it with `VectorPlot` and have gotten the desired result, but I still just can't understand the above definitions. I've even read some authors saying "don't worry about how this works, but here is how you get a good picture." I just think I need to be a little more ready than that to explain things to my students.

Is it possible to draw a picture, maybe just a few arrows, and show their *vector boxes* surrounding them? And then explain the numbers used in the `VectorScale` option and how they relate to the size and shape of the *vector boxes*?

Comment: I tried to improve the format and fix possible typo, if I misunderstood some part of your question, feel free to roll back… Well, with all due respect, as a member for 2 years, you should have format this question better.

Answer (score 14):

The option `VectorPoints` determines how many vector boxes there are.  The plot domain is subdivided into a grid, whose grid points span the plot domain in each direction.  Equal-size rectangular boxes surround each grid point so that the boxes are adjacent and tile the plot range (ignoring any padding).

Here is a picture with `VectorPoints -> 9` (the default is 15):

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 VectorPoints -> 9, 
 GridLines -> With[{n = 8}, {#, #} &@Range[-1 - 1/n, 1 + 1/n, 2/n]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a utility function I'll use to explore various settings:

```
vsplot[unitlen_, aratio_: Automatic, sfun_: Automatic, vf_: {x, y}] :=
  VectorPlot[vf, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  VectorPoints -> 9, 
  GridLines -> With[{n = 8}, {#, #} &@Range[-1 - 1/n, 1 + 1/n, 2/n]], 
  VectorScale -> {unitlen, aratio, sfun}]
```

**unitlen**

With `unitlen = 1/9` (middle), the longest vector just fits in the box and the rest are scaled proportionally.  Here the length is 1/9 the overall width of the domain, where the 9 is the number of `PlotPoints`.  If using the default, the `PlotPoints` are 15 and the corresponding `unitlen` should be `1/15`.  Other settings are scaled versions of this, either exceeding the boundaries of the boxes or staying well within the box.

```
GraphicsRow@Table[vsplot[l], {l, {1/5, 1/9, 1/12}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**aratio**

A numeric setting makes all arrowheads an absolute constant size.  With `Scaled[a]`, the size of the arrowhead depends on the length of the vector. [@xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) points out, `aratio` probably should be read as standing for "arrowhead ratio" and not "aspect ratio" as stated in the documentation for [`VectorScale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorScale.html).

```
GraphicsRow@Table[vsplot[1/9, a], {a, {1/2, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GraphicsRow@Table[vsplot[1/9, Scaled[a]], {a, {1/2, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**sfun**

The length of the vector is proportional to the value of `sfun`, which according to the documentation is to be

> a function of `x`, `y`, `fx`, `fy`, `Norm[{fx,fy}]`

I'm not sure why one would want to change the vector length, other than to make them all the same length or perhaps use things like `ArcTan[#5] &` or `Log[#5] &` to attenuate the rapid growth of the length of the vectors of a vector field.

The columns below each show the same vector field scaled according to one of the arguments.  The last pair are roughly inversely proportional to the length of the vector, which give somewhat misleading views of the actual vector fields.

```
GraphicsGrid@
 Table[Show[vsplot[1/9, Automatic, f, vf], 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{sfun, "=", f, ", ", {fx, fy}, "=", vf}], 
   ImageSize -> 200],
  {f, {#1 &, #2 &, #3 &, #4 &, 1/(1 + #5) &}},
  {vf, {{x, y}, {-y + x, y + x}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: _1._ Is "With unitlen = **1** (middle)" a typo? _2._ So you think _aratio_ is short for _arrowhead ratio_ rather than _aspect ratio_?

Comment: What a nice answer! +1

Comment: @xzczd Yes a typo...of sorts. I think I mixed it up with `aratio` when I wrote it.  Thanks.  Now that you point it out, yes, I think "aspect ratio" must be a typo in the docs.  I certainly think it's the arrowhead ratio, but I hadn't connected it with the *a* in *aratio* before.  Thanks, again. :)

Comment: +1 Something like this should be included in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Get intuition from this:

```
Manipulate[
     VectorPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[y]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
     VectorScale -> {mysize, aratio}],
         {mysize, {Small, Medium, Large}},
          {aratio, .1, 1, .1}]
```

Here, `mysize` merely states how long a vector is (by gving a size of a bounding box).  Here `aratio` ($0<aratio<1$) merely states the ratio of the size of the arrowhead to the length of the arrow line.  My version (10.0.0) does not support `sfun`.

Or try this to get a box:

```
    Manipulate[
 VectorPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2},
  {x, -3, 3},
  {y, -3, 3},
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
  StreamPoints -> Coarse,
  StreamScale -> Full,
  VectorScale -> {unitlen, aratio, sfun},
  StreamStyle -> 
   Arrowheads[{{0.03, Automatic, 
      Graphics[{FaceForm[Yellow], EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Red]], 
        Rectangle[1/unitlen {-sfun/2, -aratio/2}, 
         1/unitlen {sfun/2, aratio/2}]}]}}]],
 {unitlen, .1, 1},
 {aratio, .1, .5},
 {sfun, .1, 10}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "My version (10.0.0) does not support _sfun_."? (You did set it in your second sample.) Anyway, +1, I didn't know `StreamPoints` etc. can be used inside `VectorPlot`!