# One less arrow vector than asked for

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

Consider the following code:

```
f[t_, y_] := t + y;
VectorPlot[(#1/Norm[#1] &)[{1, f[t, y]}], {t, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {t, y},
 VectorPoints -> 11,
 VectorScale -> Tiny,
 VectorStyle -> {"Segment", GrayLevel[0.5]}
 ]
```

But I only get 10 by 10 vectors instead of 11 by 11. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: i get the expected output (11 by 11 vector points) in version 9 (Windows 8 64bit). In version 10, something strange is happening with `VectorPoints->11` -- other values seem to work fine.

Comment: Try with `{t, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}`. Is the result as expected?

Comment: Desired result in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1. I think it's reasonable to consider it as a bug.

Comment: Interestingly this works on 10.0.1 but is broken again on 10.0.2

Comment: related [73950](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73950/5478).

Comment: Using the range that @user9660 suggests, it seems to work as expected.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

In version `13.2.0` if we grab the code from the O.P we get $11 \times 12$.
The work-around that was suggested in the comments, i.e change `{t, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}` to `{t, -4, 4},{y, -4, 4}` also does not work in this version; I checked that it works fine in `12.0`. The following gives $11 \times 11$ vectors.

**Note that the following work-around is for `v13.2` and for `v13.1`.**

```
f[t_, y_] := t + y;
VectorPlot[
 (#1/Norm[#1] &)[{1, f[t, y]}],
 {t, -3, 3},
 {y, -3, 3},
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {t, y},
 VectorPoints -> {11,11},
 VectorScale -> Tiny,
 VectorStyle -> {"Segment", GrayLevel[0.5]}]
```

> [image: plot]

**The following work-around is for `v12.0`. It has, also, been suggested in the comments for earlier versions.**

```
f[t_, y_] := t + y;
VectorPlot[
 (#1/Norm[#1] &)[{1, f[t, y]}],
 {t, -4, 4},
 {y, -4, 4},
 Frame -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {t, y},
 VectorPoints -> 11,
 VectorScale -> Tiny,
 VectorStyle -> {"Segment", GrayLevel[0.5]}]
```

> [image: v12]

Neither of the work-arounds presented above works in `v13.0`